# How to create a set where the input is either an object or an iterable

Tags: python

I want to create a set from an input parameter but I want the input parameter to either be a set or a single object. If a set is passed then the result stays a set, if an object is passed in the set will contain just that single object.

I expected to be able to do

```
set(object)
```

But that throws an error

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable (if object is of type int)

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is your end goal. What data structure do you expect to have in the end, in both use cases?

Comment: in both cases, a set

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what is your expected types of `object`?

Comment: @Green either something that is Iterable or something that is not Iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) with [`Iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Iterable) to check `object` and create `set` either from original object or from tuple with single element.

```
from collections.abc import Iterable
...
new_set = set(object if isinstance(object, Iterable) else (object, ))
```

Another option how to check is object iterable is try to create set from an original object and create set from tuple in case if `TypeError` raised:

```
try:
    new_set = set(object) # will throw TypeError is object is not iterable
except TypeError:
    new_set = set((object, ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the most concise way to achieve this is with `.update` and catching `TypeError`. This will also work for updating a previously created, non-empty set.

```
input_int = 1
input_set = {2, 3}
new_set = set()

def update_set(s, obj):
    try:
        s.update(obj)
    except TypeError:
        s.update([obj])

update_set(new_set, input_int)
update_set(new_set, input_set)
print(new_set)
```

outputs

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: But why do you need to define function for updating already created empty set instead of creating new?

Comment: @OlvinRoght because that's the most generic way to do this. `new_set` might not be new. OP might want to add to a previously created set

Comment: Yes, it could be, I just don't see this in question.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I like to answer questions in a more generic fashion. Saves the OP and us from a follow-up question/edit